# Centos 5.4 wont boot

Tags: linux, centos, boot, grub

I have three disks in a centos server but it won boot,I have no grub at all.I tried to install grub with super grub and fix the system with rescatux but in vain.Is there a way to boot into centos?Here is the report

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => install-mbr/Testdisk is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Lilo is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => Grub2 (v1.97-1.98) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc and looks at sector 
    1 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (md/0)/boot/grub on this drive.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdd.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext3
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext3
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  CentOS release 5.3 (Final)
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext3
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext3
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext3
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext3
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext3
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext3
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdd1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03 2014-10-06................................................2....0............A20 gate n
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32832 of /dev/sdd1 for its 
                       second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the /multiboot 
                       directory. No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /multiboot/rescatux-0.40b11/efi/boot/bootia32.efi 
                       /multiboot/rescatux-0.40b11/efi/boot/bootx64.efi

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda
```

Comment: CentOS 5 reaches end of life this quarter, and this particular server hasn't had updates for almost a decade. You're better off to just build a new server on a currently supported OS and migrate the application. Then make sure someone is actually doing regular maintenance on it.

Comment: Try to choose the second disk as first for boot in BIOS settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the rescue mode on a CentOS installation disk.
https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-rescuemode-boot.html

Comment: I tried it but it does not work

Comment: It helps when you add the results of this tests in your question...